# How can I find the missing figure in a confrontation between two MySQL tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, one table and a table users notifications. I have to select the users who have not yet received notifications. I have tried in various ways, such as by using this query:

```
SELECT user.registration_id FROM user 
LEFT JOIN notify ON user.registration_id = notify.registration_id
```

But it does not work. How can I solve?

Also you link the structures of the two tables that use. Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `registration_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `login_username` varchar(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `notify` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `registration_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(15) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `start_notify` datetime NOT NULL,
  `stop_notify` datetime NOT NULL,
  `partial_score` int(15) unsigned NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `WHERE` statement to find the users, who haven't had a notification yet:

```
SELECT user.registration_id 
FROM user 
  LEFT JOIN notify 
    ON user.registration_id = notify.registration_id
WHERE notify.id IS NULL;
```

This will retrieve all user ids for users who do not have an entry in the notify table.

Comment: Really really thanks, was too easy! I'm not thinking about that.